# .contains() inside of for loop

Tags: java

I'm using a for loop to iterate over persisted form objects on validation and then compare against non persisted form objects. I'm using .contains in the loop, however the first loop returns true and every other loop returns false even though the pr object doesn't contain the prPersist object. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong, or if there is a better way to handle this? Thanks

Hibernate Entity

PurchaseRequest Object

```
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "purchaseRequest", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)

public List<LineItem> getLineItems() {
    if(lineItems == null ){
        lineItems = new ArrayList<LineItem>();
    }
    return lineItems;
}

public void setLineItems(List<LineItem> lineItems) {
    this.lineItems = lineItems;
}
```

LineItem Object

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "pr_id", nullable = false)
private PurchaseRequest purchaseRequest;

public PurchaseRequest getPurchaseRequest() {
    return purchaseRequest;
}

public void setPurchaseRequest(PurchaseRequest purchaseRequest) {
    this.purchaseRequest = purchaseRequest;
}
```

Page Class

```
    private List<LineItem> lineItems;

    private PurchaseRequest pr;

    @Persist
    private PurchaseRequest prPersist;

    System.out.println("prPersist size " + prPersist != null ? prPersist.getLineItems().size() : "");
    System.out.println("pr size outer loop " + pr.getLineItems().size());
    if(prPersist != null) {
        for(LineItem _lineItem : prPersist.getLineItems()) {
            System.out.println("pr lineItem object value " + _lineItem.getQuantity());
            System.out.println("pr lineItem size inner loop " + pr.getLineItems().size());
            System.out.println("pr lineItem contains prPersist lineItem " + pr.getLineItems().contains(_lineItem));
            if(!pr.getLineItems().contains(_lineItem)) {
                _lineItem.setPurchaseRequest(pr);
                pr.getLineItems().add(_lineItem);
                System.out.println("new line item added");
            }
        }
        prPersist = null;
    }
```

Printout results

```
prPersist size 2
pr size outer loop 0
pr lineItem object value 4
pr lineItem size inner loop 0
pr lineItem contains prPersist lineItem false
new line item added
pr lineItem object value 5
pr lineItem size inner loop 1
pr lineItem contains prPersist lineItem true
```

Setting prPersist

```
void onValidate() {
    prPersist = null;

    if (form.getHasErrors()) {
        prPersist = pr;            
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the definition of `LineItem.equals(Object)`? (The behavior of `Collection<LineItem>.contains(...)` depends on it.) Also -- exactly what type of object does `PurchaseRequest.getLineItems()` return? If it returns a `HashSet` or `TreeSet`, then you'll need to look at other methods of `ListItem` as well, such as `hashCode` (for `Hashset`) and `compareTo` (for `TreeSet`).

Comment: contains method depends on the LineItem and how you overriden 'equalsTo' and 'hashCode' methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that `prPersist` and 'pr' are different instances I'm guessing the `LineItem`s each contains can be different instances?

If so, I'd guess you've got a problem with you implementation of the `equals` method on `LineItem`.

Comment: I think your right, I was hoping to compare the two objects seeing prPersist is just a copy of pr. See my latest question updates for more info. Thanks Nick.

Comment: What do you mean by 'compare'?  The `Collection.contains` method uses the `Object.equals` method to determine whether a collection 'contains' a given object.  In Java by default the `Object.equals` method is doing nothing more that comparing instances, so it doesn't matter if you have two objects with the same values for all their field, they won't be considered equal by default.  You need to override the `Object.equals` method if you need this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be enough information to go on. Try printing the contents of `pr.getLineItems()` and `_lineItem` right before contains().

Comment: Hopefully I was able to provide enough useful information now. Thanks.

Comment: @George, you need to post the **contents** of the list, not its size. Also please post the equals() implementation or `LineItem`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, however I was able to resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to simplify the contains condition by replacing it with the following code.

```
    if(prPersist != null) {
        for(LineItem _lineItem : prPersist.getLineItems()) {
            if(_lineItem.getId() == null) {
                _lineItem.setPurchaseRequest(pr);
                pr.getLineItems().add(_lineItem);
            }
        }
        prPersist = null;
    }
```